# How to remove default focus set on combobox in winform

Tags: winforms

In windows form, I have 5-7 combobox on one 3 tab pages of tab control.

This tab control reside in a group box.
There are other two groupboxes containg other text box and listview controls.

Problem is, When defualt load the form control then focus set on combobox and unable to unselect.

Tried by changing property- causevalidation to false but no output.

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a line on Page Load to set focus on the control you want to focus.
For Ex:

txtName.Focus();

**EDIT**

Use this

```
ActiveControl = yourcontrolNameToWhichYouWantToSetFocus;
```

Comment: Can you pls post the image of the form?

Comment: Unable to do that as it is on client machine and no access on clipboard. It is just win form having three group box where first one containing date pickers,dropdowns and buttons and second one contains listview and third one contains tab control having three tabs. and first tab's one of combobox got focus which is not able to unfocus/deselect.

Comment: Working on it. Hold on, i ll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TabIndex of the controls, the lowest index will be the first focused. (TabStop should be true)

Comment: If you have Control inside Control put "0" as TabIndex to the whole hierarchy (for wanted focused control).

Answer (score 0):

I you want to set focus to another combobox you should call Select() method.